# What result array return in Location.distanceBetween(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, results);

Tags: java, android

```
                    final float[] results = new float[3];

                    Location.distanceBetween(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, results);

                    distance = (double)results[0];
```

I want to calculate distance in meter but i dont understand what results returns in meter or something

Answer (score 2):

Read [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29) before ask a question!

> > Computes the approximate distance in meters between two locations, and optionally the initial and final bearings of the shortest path
> >     between them. Distance and bearing are defined using the WGS84
> >     ellipsoid.
>
> The computed distance is stored in results[0]. If results has length 2
>   or greater, the initial bearing is stored in results[1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29). If results
>   has length 3 or greater, the final bearing is stored in results[2].

There are all information what this method returns in array.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation

```
Computes the approximate distance in meters between two locations
```

[click here for more info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why you didn't try to search for it by yourself? Any ways :

Computes the approximate distance in meters between two locations, and optionally the initial and final bearings of the shortest path between them. Distance and bearing are defined using the WGS84 ellipsoid.

The computed distance is stored in results[0]. If results has length 2 or greater, the initial bearing is stored in results[1]. If results has length 3 or greater, the final bearing is stored in results[2].

Parameters
startLatitude   the starting latitude
startLongitude  the starting longitude
endLatitude the ending latitude
endLongitude    the ending longitude
results an array of floats to hold the results
Throws
IllegalArgumentException    if results is null or has length < 1

From : [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double), double, double, double, float[])

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned for Android dev guide:

The computed distance is stored in results[0]. If results has length 2 or greater, the initial bearing is stored in results[1]. If results has length 3 or greater, the final bearing is stored in results[2].